# How do I send a WPF form to a library function?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I replicate the below code from Winforms to WPF ?

I have this function in `MyLibrary` Static Class which I aim to call it from the destructor of WPF form.

1. How do I implement the function?
2. How do I call the function?

Function:

```
public static void EmptyFields(Control parent)
{
     try
     {
          foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
          {
              if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
              {
                  ((TextBox)(c)).Text = string.Empty;
              }

              if (c.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
              {
                  ((ComboBox)(c)).Text = string.Empty;
              }

              if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
              {
                  ((CheckBox)(c)).Checked = false;
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
          //System write e.Message; 
      } 
}
```

Calling :

```
OpSupLib.EmptyFields(this);
```

Comment: Did you check the answer ??

Comment: Brill! that worked like a charm...Thank you ever so much...

On a different note, I know this was a bad example but the idea wasn't about only clearing the fields (which otherwise should be done by binding each control to a class method) but to generalize functions in a static class which can be used from different forms (I prefer to refer them so) 

Thank you once again, unfortunately I couldn't vote for you as i'm new to this forum.

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you should use `UIElementCollection` so change the `Control` to `UIElementCollection`. Also in WPF you should use the `IsChecked` property of `CheckBox` and use `MessageBox.Show(e.Message);` to show a message. It should be something like this:

```
public static void EmptyFields(UIElementCollection parent)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                ((TextBox)(c)).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (c.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
            {
                ((ComboBox)(c)).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                ((CheckBox)(c)).IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
OpSupLib.EmptyFields(grid.Children); // Suppose your elements are inside a container called grid
```